# Show images retrieved from database (C# and JS)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I see that there already are many topics that look like mine, but after some research and effort, I still haven't found one that helps solving my specific problem.

I have written C# code that retrieves image references from a database. This code seems to work as expected. I have also written som JS code that should use the mentioned reference to put in a "src" on a html page. The JS code is surely the problem, since it doesn't do what I am trying to make it do. I don't know how to run this JS code, since it should run on page load, and not when a user clicks a button or link. 
The code is as followed:

Htm code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">    
    <script src="JS/ImageFromDB/ImageDBHandler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:Literal ID="literal" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
      <div id="slideshow">  
         <img id="imageView" src="" alt="" class="active" runat="server" />
      </div> 
    </asp:Content>
```

The server side code:

```
 public string LoadImagesFromDB()
    {
        Sql sql = new Sql();
        string query = "SELECT Location FROM GalleryImages";
        MySqlCommand cmd = sql.Command(query);
        DataTable dt = sql.DataTable(cmd);

        string images= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var images= [";

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            images+= "\"" + HttpUtility.UrlDecode(row["Location"].ToString()) + "\",";
        }

        images = billeder.Substring(0, billeder.Length - 1);
        images += "];</script>";

        return images;
    }
```

And JS code:
And this is where everything falls apart I think. I don't know how to write the JS code so that it will do the job. The result of 'images[this.length] is something like:
'http:www.host.com/Folder/imageFile.jpg'. I'm pretty sure this is wrong though, but I don't know what to write there instead. Im surprised that the images[this.length] doesn't return a number (the length, which of course would be useless).

```
function imageSlider() {        
    $("#imageView").attr("src", images[this.length]);
}
```

---------------------------------Just in case-----------------------------------

Here is the c# class for the html page. This class calls the class that makes queries from the database.

```
    private WebLogic logic = new WebLogic();

    public void GetImageForView()
        {
            string images= logic.LoadImagesFromDB(); 
            literal.Text = images;
     //       imageView.Src = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(images);
        }
```

I really hope you expert guys can help me out, I've been struggling with this for 3 days straight.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems chaotic. From what I understand you would like to download a list of urls pointing to images and then show them using imageView image. First of all you extremely need at least basic JS knowledge to understand what is going on. I see you are already using jQuery. If you encounter errors you should check if jQuery library is properly included in you website (e.g. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=231). You should also become friendly with browser developer tools according to browser you are using and planning to be compatible with (e.g. Firebug, Chrome Developer tools, F12 in IE, etc.).

What you can do, regarding to your question, is call your server method LoadImagesFromDB using AJAX call (http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/09/12/calling-server-side-method-using-jquery-ajax.aspx). A function responsible for such call may look like this, e.g.

```
var getImages = function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "YourPage.aspx/LoadImagesFromDB",
                       data: "{}",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       async: true,
                       cache: false,
                       success: imagesUrlsReceived
                   });
                   return false;
              };
```

What you need next is to modify your server-side method: it must be static and it must be decorated with [**WebMethod**] attribute. What is more, you do not include script tags, etc. All you should return is a string array containing your urls (I did not check your url creation procedure, you can verify if this generates correct links on your own). It may look similar to the code below:

```
public static string[] LoadImagesFromDB()
    {
        Sql sql = new Sql();
        string query = "SELECT Location FROM GalleryImages";
        MySqlCommand cmd = sql.Command(query);
        DataTable dt = sql.DataTable(cmd);

        string[] images = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

        for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            images[i] = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(dt.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString());
        }

        return images;
    }
```

Now you need to save the results returned from server (an array of URL strings) in a JavaScript variable on client's side. You can do that e.g. using jQuery's ready event on document. What you do is: you trigger getImages() and in imagesUrlsReceived you fill the images variable with results.

```
var images = [];

var imagesUrlsReceived = function(results) {
    if (results === undefined) {
        alert('Something went wrong while returning results from server!');
        return;
    }

    for (var i in results) {
        images.push(results[i]);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
   getImages();
});
```

And now the most important part. Your call (at least with this little info) that states

```
function imageSlider() {        
    $("#imageView").attr("src", images[this.length]);
}
```

makes less than little sense for now. You should read about scope and this in JavaScript (e.g. http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/). I think you would like to show a picture from the images list. To show e.g. first picture from the list you can do it like this:

```
function showFirstImage() {        
    $("#imageView").attr("src", images[0]);
}
```

Naturally this is not the most generic solution we may think of, that is why we can implement it like this:

```
function imageSlider(imageNum) {        
    $("#imageView").attr("src", images[imageNum]);
}
```

where imageNum is an 0-based index of the image in images array. What is worth mentioning is that imageSlider function should be called no earlier than when images variable is filled with URLs downloaded from server. Otherwise images variable remains empty.

There is a lot to do here apart from what I have sketched. You should take care of possible errors (what if I pass a string instead of a number as imageNum, what if imageNum is null, or undefined, or the imageNum is out of bounds, e.g. less than 0 or greater than images.length?).

However, I think I have given you a rough plan what course of action should be taken in this case. I do not guarantee this to be cut and paste code, it is to serve as an illustration and guidance, not a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense. I'm sure it will help. I'll follow the approach

Comment: OK, then I am glad. Let me know if you get stuck somewhere. If you do it and it works then please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi again. How will fill the var images = [];? I'm also kinda stuck on this method: imagesUrlsReceived = function(results). How will the "result" paramater look, and where will give that as an argument?

Comment: Specifically, I am thinking how I will get the data recieved from the: url: "YourPage.aspx/LoadImagesFromDB"